# Javascript alert function not displaying message after clicking button

Tags: javascript, html

Having an issue where I can't get the alert to display after clicking the button. I've edited the code from what it previously was according to the suggestions made and still not getting the alert to display. Any other thoughts on what the issue could be? I appreciate and thank you all for the help.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open Sans' rel='stylesheet'>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Pizzeria</title>

    <style type="text/css">

      body {
        margin: 40px;
        font-family: 'Open Sans';
      }
      #fieldSize, #fieldCrust {
        width: 150px;
        float: left;
        border: none;
      }
       #fieldToppings {
         width: 350px;
         border: none;

       }
       fieldset {
         margin-top: 20px;
       }
      #toppings1 {
        float: left;
      }
      label {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 150px;
        margin: 7px;
        text-align: left;
      }
      input[type="text"] {
        width: 250px;
      }
      div {
        padding: 10px;
      }
      #btnOrder {
        width: auto;
        border-radius: 10px;
      }

    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      function orderSubmit() {
        var name = document.getElementById("txtName").value;
        var phone = document.getElementById("txtPhone").value;
        phone = '(' + phone.substring(0,3) + ')' + phone.substring(3,6) + '-' + phone.substring(6);
        var address = document.getElementById("txtAddress").value;

        var msg = name + ", your order is being prepared. \n";
        msg+= "Your order will be delivered at " + address;
        msg+= "Your contact infromation is: " + phone "\n";
        msg+= "Order details: \n \n";


        for(var i = 0; i < document.frm1.rdoSize.length; i++) {
           if(document.frm1.rdoSize[i].checked) {
             var radioStateSize = document.frm1.rdoSize[i].value;
           }
        }
        for(var j = 0; j < document.frm1.rdoCrust.length; j++) {
           if(document.frm1.rdoCrust[j].checked) {
             var radioStateCrust = document.frm1.rdoCrust[j].value;
           }
        }
        msg+= radioStateSize + ' ' + radioStateCrust + " pizza with the following toppings: \n";

        var chkToppings = document.frm1.chkToppings;

        for(k=0; k < document.frm1.chkToppings; k++) {
           if(document.frm1.chkToppings[k].checked) {
           msg += document.frm1.chkToppings[k].value + ' ';
           }
        }
        alert(msg);
      }

    </script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <fieldset id="main">
      <legend><h2>Pizza Order!</h2></legend>

      <form name="frm1">
        <div>
          <label for="lblName">Name:</label>
          <input type="text" id="txtName">
        </div>

        <div>
          <label for="lblPhone">Phone Number:</label>
          <input type="text" id="txtPhone">
        </div>

        <div>
          <label for="lblAddress">Address:</label>
          <input type="text" id="txtAddress">
        </div>

      <fieldset id="fieldSize">
        <legend><strong>Size</strong></legend>
          <input type="radio" name="rdoSize" value="Small" id="rdoSmall"> Small <br>
          <input type="radio" name="rdoSize" value="Medium" id="rdoMedium"> Medium <br>
          <input type="radio" name="rdoSize" value="Large" id="rdoLarge"> Large <br>
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset id="fieldCrust">
        <legend><strong>Crust</strong></legend>
          <input type="radio" name="rdoCrust" value="Thin" id="rdoThin"> Small <br>
          <input type="radio" name="rdoCrust" value="HandTossed" id="rdoHandTossed"> Hand Tossed <br>
          <input type="radio" name="rdoCrust" value="GF" id="rdoGF"> Gluten Free <br>
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset id="fieldToppings">
        <legend><strong>Toppings</strong></legend>
          <div id="toppings1">
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkToppings" id="chkPepperoni" value="Pepperoni"> Pepperoni <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkToppings" id="chkSausage" value="Sausage"> Sausage <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkToppings" id="chkChourico" value="Chourico"> Pepperoni <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkToppings" id="chkChicken" value="Chicken"> Chicken <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkToppings" id="chkAnchovies" value="Anchovies"> Anchovies <br>
          </div>
          <div id="toppings2">
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkToppings" id="chkMushrooms" value="Mushrooms"> Mushrooms <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkToppings" id="chkPeppers" value="Peppers"> Peppers <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkToppings" id="chkFeta" value="Feta"> Feta <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkToppings" id="chkOlives" value="Olives"> Olives <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkToppings" id="chkOnions" value="Onions"> Onions <br>
          </div>
      </fieldset>

      <input type="button" id="btnOrder" value="Order" onclick="orderSubmit()">

      </form>
    </fieldset>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your JavaScript is full of syntax errors, the alert not showing up is the last of your problems. `.[i]` is not a valid JavaScript syntax, `.value ' '` is totally unclear in the scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the example you posted, there are some typos and syntax errors, you may want to check for that first. You can check for those using the console (in some browsers: Ctrl-i), which is always useful for debugging BTW. As pointed in other answers, when using brackets, you don't need to use the dot ( rdoCrust.[j] )

Answer (score 0):

Right at the beginning of your `orderSubmit` function you have a semicolon that has adventured off into a strange location right after the the parentheses like so:

```js
function orderSubmit(); {
```

Whereas it should look like this:

```js
function orderSubmit() {
```

Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple problems

An extra semicolon here:

```
function orderSubmit(); {
```

here:

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.frm1.rdoSize.length; i++); {
```

and here:

```
for (var j = 0; j < document.frm1.rdoCrust.length; j++); {
```

An extra point before brackets here:

```
if (document.frm1.rdoSize.[i].checked) {
```

and here:

```
if (document.frm1.rdoCrust.[j].checked) {
```

and a missing plus sign here:

```
msg += document.frm1.chkToppings[k].value + ' ';
```

Comment: I've edited my code based on your suggestions I would appreciate if you could check it again.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function orderSubmit(){
    var name = document.getElementById("txtName").value;
    var phone = document.getElementById("txtPhone").value;
    phone = '(' + phone.substring(0,3) + ')' + phone.substring(3,6) + '-' + phone.substring(6);
    var address = document.getElementById("txtAddress").value;

    var msg = name + ", your order is being prepared. \n";
    msg+= "Your order will be delivered at " + address;
    msg+= "Order details: \n \n";


    var radioStateSize = document.getElementsByName('rdoSize')
    radioStateSize.forEach((r)=>{
      if(r.checked){msg += r.value}
    })

    var radioStateCrust = document.getElementsByName('rdoCrust')
    radioStateCrust.forEach((r)=>{
      if(r.checked){msg += ' '+r.value+" pizza with the following toppings: \n"}
    })

    var chkToppings = document.getElementsByName('chkToppings')
    chkToppings.forEach((r)=>{
      if(r.checked){msg += ' '+r.value}
    })
    
    alert(msg);
  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems with the solution you developed:

1. Used without defining the variable `k` in the for loop.
2. `for();` statement prevents the block from executing depending on the loop.

In the solution below, both radio buttons and checkboxes are checked.

```js
let submitButton = document.getElementById('btnOrder');
let nameElement = document.getElementById('txtName');
let phoneElement = document.getElementById('txtPhone');
let addressElement = document.getElementById('txtAddress');

function getPhoneValue(value) {
  let result = '(' + value.substring(0,3) + ')' + value.substring(3,6) + '-' + value.substring(6);
  return result;
}

function getRadioButtonValue(element) {
  let result; 
  
  if(element !== null)
    result = element.value;
  else
    result = "null";
    
  return result;
}

submitButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  let phone = getPhoneValue(phoneElement.value);
  var msg = `Name: ${nameElement.value} Address:  ${addressElement.value} Phone: ${phone}\n Order details: `;

  /* first radio button group */
  var radioStateSize = getRadioButtonValue(document.querySelector("input[name='rdoSize']:checked"));
  
  /* second radio button group */
  var radioStateCrust = getRadioButtonValue(document.querySelector("input[name='rdoCrust']:checked"));
  
  /* user notification */
  msg += `${radioStateSize} ${radioStateCrust} pizza with the following toppings:\n`;
  
  /* checkbox group */
  var chkToppings;
  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[name='chkToppings']:checked");
  checkboxes.forEach((checkbox) => {
    msg += checkbox.value + " ";
  });
  
  console.clear();
  console.log(msg)
  alert(msg);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 40px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}
#fieldSize, #fieldCrust {
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  border: none;
}
 #fieldToppings {
   width: 350px;
   border: none;

 }
 fieldset {
   margin-top: 20px;
 }
#toppings1 {
  float: left;
}
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 7px;
  text-align: left;
}
input[type="text"] {
  width: 250px;
}
div {
  padding: 10px;
}
#btnOrder {
  width: auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <fieldset id="main">
    <legend><h2>Pizza Order!</h2></legend>
      <form name="frm1">
        <div>
          <label for="lblName">Name:</label>
          <input type="text" id="txtName">
        </div>

        <div>
          <label for="lblPhone">Phone Number:</label>
          <input type="text" id="txtPhone">
        </div>

        <div>
          <label for="lblAddress">Address:</label>
          <input type="text" id="txtAddress">
        </div>

      <fieldset id="fieldSize">
        <legend><strong>Size</strong></legend>
          <input type="radio" name="rdoSize" value="Small" id="rdoSmall"> Small <br>
          <input type="radio" name="rdoSize" value="Medium" id="rdoMedium"> Medium <br>
          <input type="radio" name="rdoSize" value="Large" id="rdoLarge"> Large <br>
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset id="fieldCrust">
        <legend><strong>Crust</strong></legend>
          <input type="radio" name="rdoCrust" value="Thin" id="rdoThin"> Small <br>
          <input type="radio" name="rdoCrust" value="HandTossed" id="rdoHandTossed"> Hand Tossed <br>
          <input type="radio" name="rdoCrust" value="GF" id="rdoGF"> Gluten Free <br>
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset id="fieldToppings">
        <legend><strong>Toppings</strong></legend>
          <div id="toppings1">
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkToppings" id="chkPepperoni" value="Pepperoni"> Pepperoni <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkToppings" id="chkSausage" value="Sausage"> Sausage <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkToppings" id="chkChourico" value="Chourico"> Pepperoni <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkToppings" id="chkChicken" value="Chicken"> Chicken <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkToppings" id="chkAnchovies" value="Anchovies"> Anchovies <br>
          </div>
          <div id="toppings2">
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkToppings" id="chkMushrooms" value="Mushrooms"> Mushrooms <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkToppings" id="chkPeppers" value="Peppers"> Peppers <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkToppings" id="chkFeta" value="Feta"> Feta <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkToppings" id="chkOlives" value="Olives"> Olives <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkToppings" id="chkOnions" value="Onions"> Onions <br>
          </div>
      </fieldset>
      <input type="button" id="btnOrder" value="Order">
    </form>
  </fieldset>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You had a type here `msg+= "Your contact infromation is: " + phone "\n";` you must add `+` between `phone + "\n";`.

You can run the snippet below, it works.

```js
function orderSubmit() {
  var name = document.getElementById("txtName").value;
  var phone = document.getElementById("txtPhone").value;
  phone = "(" + phone.substring(0,3) + ")" + phone.substring(3,6) + "-" + phone.substring(6);
  var address = document.getElementById("txtAddress").value;

  var msg = name + ", your order is being prepared. \n";
  msg+= "Your order will be delivered at " + address;
  msg+= "Your contact infromation is: " + phone + "\n"; // <- Problem is that you forgot "+"
  msg+= "Order details: \n \n";


  for(var i = 0; i < document.frm1.rdoSize.length; i++) {
     if(document.frm1.rdoSize[i].checked) {
       var radioStateSize = document.frm1.rdoSize[i].value;
     }
  }
  for(var j = 0; j < document.frm1.rdoCrust.length; j++) {
     if(document.frm1.rdoCrust[j].checked) {
       var radioStateCrust = document.frm1.rdoCrust[j].value;
     }
  }
  msg+= radioStateSize + " " + radioStateCrust + " pizza with the following toppings: \n";

  var chkToppings = document.frm1.chkToppings;
  for(var k=0; k < document.frm1.chkToppings; k++) { // add var k
     if(document.frm1.chkToppings[k].checked)
     msg += document.frm1.chkToppings[k].value + ' ';
  }
  alert(msg);
}
```

```css
body {
        margin: 40px;
        font-family: 'Open Sans';
      }
      #fieldSize, #fieldCrust {
        width: 150px;
        float: left;
        border: none;
      }
       #fieldToppings {
         width: 350px;
         border: none;

       }
       fieldset {
         margin-top: 20px;
       }
      #toppings1 {
        float: left;
      }
      label {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 150px;
        margin: 7px;
        text-align: left;
      }
      input[type="text"] {
        width: 250px;
      }
      div {
        padding: 10px;
      }
      #btnOrder {
        width: auto;
        border-radius: 10px;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open Sans' rel='stylesheet'>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Gianni's Pizzeria</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <fieldset id="main">
      <legend><h2>Pizza Order!</h2></legend>

      <form name="frm1">
        <div>
          <label for="lblName">Name:</label>
          <input type="text" id="txtName">
        </div>

        <div>
          <label for="lblPhone">Phone Number:</label>
          <input type="text" id="txtPhone">
        </div>

        <div>
          <label for="lblAddress">Address:</label>
          <input type="text" id="txtAddress">
        </div>

      <fieldset id="fieldSize">
        <legend><strong>Size</strong></legend>
          <input type="radio" name="rdoSize" value="Small" id="rdoSmall"> Small <br>
          <input type="radio" name="rdoSize" value="Medium" id="rdoMedium"> Medium <br>
          <input type="radio" name="rdoSize" value="Large" id="rdoLarge"> Large <br>
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset id="fieldCrust">
        <legend><strong>Crust</strong></legend>
          <input type="radio" name="rdoCrust" value="Thin" id="rdoThin"> Small <br>
          <input type="radio" name="rdoCrust" value="HandTossed" id="rdoHandTossed"> Hand Tossed <br>
          <input type="radio" name="rdoCrust" value="GF" id="rdoGF"> Gluten Free <br>
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset id="fieldToppings">
        <legend><strong>Toppings</strong></legend>
          <div id="toppings1">
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkToppings" id="chkPepperoni" value="Pepperoni"> Pepperoni <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkToppings" id="chkSausage" value="Sausage"> Sausage <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkToppings" id="chkChourico" value="Chourico"> Pepperoni <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkToppings" id="chkChicken" value="Chicken"> Chicken <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkToppings" id="chkAnchovies" value="Anchovies"> Anchovies <br>
          </div>
          <div id="toppings2">
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkToppings" id="chkMushrooms" value="Mushrooms"> Mushrooms <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkToppings" id="chkPeppers" value="Peppers"> Peppers <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkToppings" id="chkFeta" value="Feta"> Feta <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkToppings" id="chkOlives" value="Olives"> Olives <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkToppings" id="chkOnions" value="Onions"> Onions <br>
          </div>
      </fieldset>

      <input type="button" id="btnOrder" value="Order" onclick="orderSubmit()">

      </form>
    </fieldset>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! :)